# How can I delete a video from the gallery in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gallery

I'm trying to open the gallery and be able to select a video to delete in my app. I used this code:

```
private val pickVideoLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val data: Intent? = result.data
            videoUrl = data?.data
            // Handle the selected video URI
        }
    }
    private val deleteVideoLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            videoUrl?.let { videoUri ->
                // The video has been deleted, perform necessary actions
                // after deleting the selected video
            }
        }
    }
binding.deleteVideo.setOnClickListener {
            deleteOriginalVideoFromGallery(videoUrl)

        }

private fun deleteOriginalVideoFromGallery(videoUri: Uri?) {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        intent.type = "video/*"

        pickVideoLauncher.launch(intent)
        videoUri?.let { videoUri ->
            val deleteIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE)
            deleteIntent.data = videoUri

            deleteVideoLauncher.launch(deleteIntent)
        }
    }
```

However, I get this error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: harmony.valley.wamboocam, PID: 23073
> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.DELETE
> dat=content://media/... }
> at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2174)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1805)
> at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5596)
> at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:728)
> at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat$Api16Impl.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:809)
> at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:246)
> at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$2.onLaunch(ComponentActivity.java:243)
> at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$2.launch(ActivityResultRegistry.java:175)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$10.launch(Fragment.java:3622)
> at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher.launch(ActivityResultLauncher.java:47)
> at harmony.valley.wamboocam.HomeFragment.deleteOriginalVideoFromGallery(HomeFragment.kt:1043)
> at harmony.valley.wamboocam.HomeFragment.initUI$lambda$24$lambda$23(HomeFragment.kt:763)

I tried deleting this line:

```
deleteVideoLauncher.launch(deleteIntent)
```

but then, the Gallery opens and I'm not able to select the video to delete it. When I tap on it, the Gallery closes and I go back to the app as if nothing would have happened.

How can I solve this? At least, I would like to be able to select the video from the Gallery and delete it.

Comment: `pickVideoLauncher.launch(intent)` After that line you cannot have any code. You have to wait until the user picked a file and use the obtained uri.

Comment: @blackapps I commented the code after `pickVideoLauncher.launch(intent)` and it opens the gallery but nothing happens when I select the video I want to delete. It doesn't let me select it to delete it.

Comment: You did not change anything here. Show what you do! And dont comment. Remove.

Comment: @blackapps can you write an answer with the code? I'm sure I understand what you mean or, at least, it doesn't work. thanks

Comment: You should write the code. You did not change anything yet.

Comment: I wrote the code you mentioned on Android Studio and it doesn't work. I'm not editing my question with some advise that it's not useful